# OpenAI gym environment frames not displayed on screen in Kaggle

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to render the simple Mario environment using kaggle notebooks with the below code but when I run the code, nothing is being displayed on the screen. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image]